# error: glibc detected when using vector

Tags: c++, linux, vector

I used arrays in my code, and now I changed them to `vector` and I get these errors(its in linux):

```
glibc detected *** double free or corruption

glibc detected malloc memory corruption
```

My code is so long and I can't paste it here, here's how I use `vector`:

Declared:

```
 vector:vector<double>x;//i didnt define anysize for vector
```

for inserting a value in it:

```
x.insert(x.begin()+i,i)
```

to use an element:

```
 x.at(i)
```

just this.

What do you think about the problem? <strike>?</strike>
Additionally I don't know when I should use iterator in vector, shouldn't I use it here? <strike>?</strike>

TIA

Comment: Please just use valgrind, or post more code.

Comment: thanks,but i want to know this work that i do isnt mistake??

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `x.insert(x.begin()+i,i)`?  What is `i` here?  Why don't you just use `x.push_back(i)`?

Comment: i is an integer that has an range,i want to put for example i=5 in x[5]

Comment: @arash: You cannot insert at arbitrary positions.  If your vector has size 0, calling `x.insert(x.begin() + 5, 5)` is not allowed and might corrupt your memory.  Make sure that your vector is large enough, or use `std::map` to map arbitrary numbers.  In the latter case, your code could be as simple as `std::map<int, double> x; x[5] = 5;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that you didn't define any size for the vector. That means it has size zero.

In that case, this code

```
x.insert(x.begin()+i,i)
```

is invalid for any `i` other than zero.

Comment: wow thanks,so what should i do if i dont want to give a fixed size to vector??because it may be bigger or smaller than the size

Comment: The size isn't fixed and can be changed anytime. You just cannot "insert" anything outside of the vector. If you want to add another object at the end, the is a `push_back` function for that. Or you can just call `resize` to change the size.

Comment: thanks,but i want to insert for example number 5 in vec[5] ,so what should i do ??

Comment: As far as I know, it is not true that "you just cannot 'insert' anything outside of the vector".  `insert` resizes the vector as needed, just like `push_back()`.  Semantically, `vec.insert(vec.end(), x)` is equivalent to `vec.push_back(x)`.

Comment: @arash: Just create an empty vector, then `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) vec.push_back(i);`.  Having said that, your code `x.insert(x.begin()+i,i)` seems unusual and error prone, yet valid, since `x.begin()+i` will always be equivalent to `x.end()`.

Comment: i mean i what to insert number 5 in vec[5] and maybe in some condition vec[6] doesnt fill and next i want to fill vec[7] with 7

Comment: @arash: It seems that you actually don't want to use `std::vector`, but `std::map<int, double>`.

Comment: @Ferdinand - `insert` works if you use it in the range begin-end. It doesn't work for other positions, like index 5 in a zero size vector.

Comment: @Bo: You are right, it does not work for arbitrary numbers.  This is why arash should consider using `std::map` instead.  I assumed that he is filling his vector incrementally in a `for` loop.

Comment: thanks,if it doesnt work with vector so i will use map,thanks so much

Answer (score 3):

This is just a wild guess (without seeing the code), but did you just replace your array from this :

```
// some code
double *array = new double[ 50 ];
// use array somehow
delete[] array;
```

into this :

```
// some code
std::vector< double > array;
// use array somehow
delete [] &array[0];
```

?

Your best bet is to run your program using valgrind, which should precisely tell you at which line is the problem.

Comment: @arash In that case, remove the line with `delete[]` and this problem should be solved. There are no needs to delete the vector, unless you allocate it on heap